# Should i create an Empty Web Application or Web API Web Application template? - VB.net

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I wanted to build a VB.net web application using MS Visual Studio 2015.  Someone suggested me to create a Web API instead of MVC project if i'm also planning to create a mobile app later on. I may use angularjs in my project so controllers will surely be used, so what should i choose when creating the project in the first place?

Because when i created a web project: File=>New Project=>ASP.net Web Application=>Empty..there are no folders for Controllers, Model, etc. Do i have to create a Controller folder on my own?

Or should i do this: File=>New Project=>ASP.net Web Application=>Web API..? sorry if its a silly question. its just that i'm afraid that if i chose the wrong project now, it'll affect the development later on.

Comment: What is your immediate requirement Web app or Mobile app ? Did you come across this before [https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api] ?

Comment: If you're going to use Angular 1 or 2, it would be better to use api. It will be easier to design and develop app as it grows big. If you have something else in mid then empty will be useful since it gives you more control.

Comment: @Searching, i couldnt access the page you recommended

Comment: Sorry here you go https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: @PratikGaikwad, yes its a big project. By API, its the same thing as web application right? There are plans to also create a mobile app for the same project, so if its possible it would be easier and handy if i could just use the same project without much changes(in other words, flexible for multiple platforms). for this, what template is applicable? I'm still new to asp.net and angularjs so i dont know what i should choose. Do you know any pdf(s) or tutorials or code examples that may be easy to follow and understand?

Comment: @Searching, no, i've never come across it before. thanks. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @Nurul I would suggest go with api. Those can be used in mobile app with little to none changes depending upon your return type and design

Comment: @Searching, i'm implementing your tutorial suggestion, but i have a question: i tried to create a System.Web.Services.WebService function in the controller in order to link to the database that i've connected to in the ConnectionStrings in web.config file, but even though i've imported the System.Web.Services class in the controller, there's still error. Is there a different way to call the database? Because previously when i implemented this way in a website project, there are no errors.

Comment: It's hard to say what exactly is wrong.  It's probably worth opening a question.  I suggest u check if the project compiled correctly and that u are able to browse to ur pages/ action. It'll help to narrow down the error.

Comment: @Searching, sorry but what do you mean by "able to browse to ur pages/ action"? i'm following the steps shown in the tutorial u recommended. i'm just at the controller part so i haven't linked it to any pages yet. Do u mean that i have to complete the whole procedure first, then only i implement the connecting-to-database part in the controller in the end phase?

Comment: Yup that's pretty much it.If you are able to build you controller/action then the next stage is to start with data access. I'm not saying complete all of them but at least a single controller/action that will return some result when you browse to it.. The link should guide you to get started not a complete solution. I suggest looking into `EntityFramework` for accessing data if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question mainly depends on your choice and needs,

for example

In Case of an empty project as name defines you will have nothing else web.config.

Benefits of it:

1. here you can define, design your own structure. you can either make
   it simple 3 tier or you can make it WEBAPI application. it's all up
   to you.

however in the case of choosing Webapi template you will have a prebuilt structure which can help you out for initial understanding

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html

benefits of it

1. You will get predefine template and structure.
2. you can utilize of webapi's which further isolate you backend logic from the frontend.
3. as you are also planning to create the mobile app. and using front end as angular, so in that case, webapi may come handy.
4. as the whole world is  moving towards webapi, so i will recommend you to use it. please refer https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/martinkearn/2015/01/05/introduction-to-rest-and-net-web-api/

so down the line it all depend on you if you want to build you application for the stretch and take full control of it regarding structuring backend etc.. then go with empty else go with Microsoft pre-define template

Thanks,

Ajay Kotnala

Comment: I'll have a look at it. Thank you very much for your explanation and suggestions! :D

Comment: Np :). please carry on. its good to ask for help sometimes. you get a different perspective of the same question. 

let me know if I can help you in some way.

Comment: Right now i'm connecting my web API project to an existing database. Someone suggested to use EntityFramework for that. I'm applying code first approach, but the problem is i'm actually supposed to just import tables, but i accidentally imported views as well. i was thinking that it will be placed in a folder,but it doesnt. so i was thinking to undo the import. this is what happens when i tried first without referring to the actual step -.-' Can you help me please? what should i do?